# getting webpack to work on openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, webpack

I'm trying to deploy a basic nodejs app to OpenShift. I'm not sure how to do it with webpack though.  Do I build the bundle.js file locally and just deploy that along with the index.html?  I tried that by putting the bundle.js file in a /public directory and pointing to that using a relative path in the index.html, but I get bundle.js not found error. (It works when I run it locally.)  What step am I missing?  Must I not use relative paths in OpenShift?  I find the documentation for OpenShift rather complicated.  If anybody out there can break this down I'd much appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

I did miss a step:  You need to add the directory in the server.js like so:

```
self.initializeServer = function() {
    self.createRoutes();
    self.app = express.createServer();

    self.app.configure(function() {
        self.app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
    });

    //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
    for (var r in self.routes) {
        self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
    }
};
```